# How to affect two labels with one UIStepper

Tags: xcode, swift, uistepper

I have a UIStepper that currently affects one label (quantity) when tapped. I would like for that same UIStepper to affect another label which is the cost. Basically, I would like for the UIStepper to update the cost as the quantity is increased. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the value of both the labels with calculations when the UIStepper value function is called

You can make the code like this in the action of the UIStepper

```
@IBAction func stepperChanged(sender: UIStepper) {

     lblQuantity.text = "\(sender.value)"
    if sender.value == 1 {
     lblCost.text = "12.5"
    } else {
        lblCost.text = "\(((sender.value-1) * 6.5) + 12.5)"
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! There's just one little issue, the base cost is 12.50 and I would like to add 6.50 per addition in quantity. How do go about that?

Comment: @J.K. means for one item it will cost 12.5 and as quantity increase add 6.5 per quantity right ?

Comment: Yes. At the moment, when the quantity is returned to 1, the base price becomes the multiplier.

Comment: Thank you very much once again. The results are multiplied by 12.5 instead of being added by 6.5. I'll be looking for a solution and let you know. If you find one in the meantime, please let me know as well. Best regards

Comment: did you check the recent change, I have updated the code (sender.value-1) instead of sender.value in the sender value, and now for me it's working like 12.5,19.25.5 etc...

Comment: Thank you very very very much!